# How to use Java Reflection with generic params

Tags: java, generics, reflection

**I need to use reflection with generic params. Here is an example class and test class of what I am trying to do. Running the test, I am getting error:**

**[ERROR : Method not found exception] : Method name 'EST2GMT'**

Here is my reflect class with generic;

```
/*
 * File: MyTransformer.java
 * Created: Jul 22, 2014
*/

package company.online.project.my.transform;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class MyTransformer< T >
{

Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger( MyTransformer.class );

public T tranform( String functionName, T arg )
{

    try
    {
        Method method = this.getClass().getDeclaredMethod( functionName, arg.getClass() );
        return (T) method.invoke( this, arg );
    }
    catch ( NoSuchMethodException e )
    {
        System.out.println( "[ERROR : Method not found exception] : Method name '" + functionName + "'" );
    }
    catch ( java.lang.IllegalAccessException e )
    {
        System.out.println( "[ERROR : Illegal Access exception] : " + e.getMessage() );
    }
    catch ( java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException e )
    {
        System.out.println( "[ERROR : Invocation Target not found exception] : " + e.getMessage() );
    }
    return null;
}

public Date convert2Date( String date )
{
    LOG.debug( "convert2Date function called" );
    return new Date();
}

public Calendar EST2GMT( Calendar estTime )
{
    LOG.debug( "EST2GMT function called :" + estTime.getTime().toString() );
    return new GregorianCalendar( 2013, 0, 31 );
}

public String createcompanyKeys( List<T> values )
{
    LOG.debug( "EST2GMT function called" );
    return "String";
}

}
```

Here is my test class :

```
package company.online.project.my.transform;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class MyTransformerTest
{

MyTransformer transformer;

@Before
public void setUp()
{
    transformer = new MyTransformer();
}

@Test
public void testGetMethod() throws SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalArgumentException,
        IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException
{
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar( 2013, 0, 31 );
    Assert.assertEquals( Calendar.class, transformer.tranform( "EST2GMT", calendar.getClass() );
}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing a `GregorianCalendar` to a method that takes a `Calendar`.  But with reflection, you didn't find any method that takes a `GregorianCalendar`, even though it's legal in normal Java method invocation to pass an instance of a subclass of the parameter's type to a method.

To find the method that takes a `Calendar`, then if you don't find a method with the exact `Class` match, catch the `NoSuchMethodException` and try again with the class's superclass, which you can get from the `Class` object with the [`getSuperclass()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass--), until you have failed to find the method even with `Object`.

Also, you are passing a `Class` object as the actual parameter to the method to be invoked using reflection.

```
transformer.tranform( "EST2GMT", calendar.getClass())
```

Pass the actual object instead.  Also, call `.getClass()` *after* the `()`s to get the class of the returned object.

```
transformer.tranform( "EST2GMT", calendar).getClass()
```

The test case will still fail, because the actual type of what's returned is `GregorianCalendar`, which is not the same class `Calendar`.  This will pass:

```
Assert.assertEquals( GregorianCalendar.class,
    transformer.tranform( "EST2GMT", calendar ).getClass() );
```

If you just want to know if it's any kind of `Calendar`, an `instanceof` will suffice:

```
Assert.assertTrue(transformer.tranform("EST2GMT", calendar) instanceof Calendar);
```

Comment: Even if you are searching with `getSuperClass()`, your test will fail because it expects a `Calendar` but gets a `GregorianCalendar` again.

Comment: tried with .getClass().getSuperClass() and still getting that error. Also tried with thid modified part in the testGetMethod(). Did not work either. Getting the same error

Comment: I've added more explanation about what went wrong with the test.